How to do a multidimensional Lomb-scargle periodogram using Python
I have 10 signals recorded by detectors which are placed in different r and phi coordinates (let's consider the situation in the polar reference system). I want to find spatial and temporal periodicities in the measurements.
Detectors record with the same temporal step but the spatial step between them are uneven. Thus I decided to use Lomb-Scargle periodogram to find the periodicities.
The problem is I have no idea how to do it by Python. I tried lombscargle function from scipy but it can process only 1D data.
So is there any Python package or other instrument to do it in 3D.
I will appreciate any help.

plomb in MATLAB handles 2D input signal. You may want to give it a shot.

@AHT
It's seems like plomb just applies its 1D version to each row of the input matrix
